# Update a column with hierarchy structure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, tree, parent-child, hierarchy

I have a `service`'s table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE service
  Id number,
  Name varchar2(50),
  ParentId number,
  PcCode varchar(50);
```

And data of the `service`'s table:

```
ID  NAME    PARENTID    PCCODE
1   Test1   0           Null
2   Test2   0           Null
3   Test3   1           Null
4   Test4   1           Null
5   Test5   1           Null
6   Test6   2           Null
7   Test7   2           Null
8   Test8   2           Null
9   Test9   2           Null
10  Test10  3           Null
11  Test11  3           Null
```

And I want to update the `PcCode` column. This is dependent on the `Id` column and the `ParentId` column.
Example:

```
 Id = 1, ParentId = 0 => PcCode = '001'
 Id = 2, ParentId = 0 => PcCode = '002'

 Id = 3, ParentId = 1 => PcCode = '001001'
 Id = 4, ParentId = 1 => PcCode = '001002'
 .....
```

**Update**

I have written 2 sp (2 way) for update `PcCode`'s column,  but I think it's not doing very good.

`Sp1`: (done)

```
create or replace 
procedure service_hierarchy
is

cursor c_service
is
select * from
service d;

cursor c_parents
is
select k.parentid from
service k
group by k.parentid
order by k.parentid;

begin
   for obj1 in c_service     
    loop
      update service e set e.pccode = lpad(to_char(rownum), 3, '0') where e.parentid = service.parentid;
    end loop;

    for obj2 in c_parents     
    loop
      update service e set e.pccode = (select f.pccode from service f where f.id = obj2.parentid) || e.pccode where e.parentid = obj2.parentid;
    end loop; 
end;
```

`Sp2`: error - It's done. But it returns a result false. And I don't know how to work correctly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE service_hierarchy_2
(
parentId NUMBER := 0
)
IS

CURSOR v_data IS
SELECT *
FROM service
WHERE parentId = parentId;


BEGIN

    IF (parentId = 0)
    THEN

    UPDATE service  SET pccode = LPAD(ROWNUM , 3, '0')
    WHERE parentid = parentId;
    ELSE
        FOR data IN v_data
        LOOP
            UPDATE service  SET pccode = (SELECT 1 FROM service WHERE Id = parentId) || LPAD(ROWNUM , 3, '0')
            WHERE parentid = parentId;

            service_hierarchy_2(data.Id);

        END LOOP;
    END IF;

END;
```

Please help me to resolve `sp2` or one way be better than 2 sp on top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting up the column for sorting, and you don't need to. Also, the query to set `PcCode` like you want to would be very difficult.

Oracle's hierarchical queries will sort by the hierarchy if you use the `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` option. The following query will read your hierarchy and order it the way I believe you want it (I've added a "path" value to show the full hierarchy branch for each row, and how it sorts correctly with `ORDER BY SIBLINGS`):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
  ParentID,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID, '/')
FROM service
START WITH ParentID = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ParentID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ID;
```

When I ran this query I got the following results:

```
ID NAME     PARENTID  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID,'/')
-- -------- --------  ---------------------------
 1 Test1           0  /1
 3 Test3           1  /1/3
10 Test10          3  /1/3/10
11 Test11          3  /1/3/11
 4 Test4           1  /1/4
 5 Test5           1  /1/5
 2 Test2           0  /2
 6 Test6           2  /2/6
 7 Test7           2  /2/7
 8 Test8           2  /2/8
 9 Test9           2  /2/9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very useful. But I want to get results as my results.